# BehaviorSubject not working Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, behaviorsubject

I cant seem to figure out what the issue is,

I have a service that has a behavior subject like so...

```
popupSource = new BehaviorSubject<any>('');

popup(component) {
   this.popupSource.next(component);
}
```

then In my header component

```
popupClick() {
    this._service.popup('example');    
}
```

then in my header.html

```
<button (click)="popupClick()"></button>
```

then In my app component

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._service.popupSource.subscribe((result) => {
       console.log(result);
    })
}
```

so whats happening is the click is firing the `this._service.popup('example');` but its never hitting the subscription...

I've put breakpoints on each function and It succesfully reaches `this.popupSource.next(component)` but then nothing?? Every Time I click the button I should be getting the console log.

Im not sure what Im doing wrong... Ive left out code for brevity sake so please let me know if you need more information

**EDIT**

Ive also tried doing

```
private popupSource = new BehaviorSubject<any>('');

getPopup = this.popupSource.asObservable();

popup(component) {
   this.popupSource.next(component);
}
```

and the in my app component listend to the getPopup instead

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._service.getPopup.subscribe((result) => {
       console.log(result);
    })
}
```

and that's not working either, I cant figure out what the problem is...

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that you have the same instance of the service ? where do you provide it ?

Comment: I have two seperate modules a main module and an app module, the app component is in the appModule and the header component is in the mainModule but I provide the service in both modules or should I be exporting it in the appModule and then grabbing it from there in the mainModule??

Comment: You should not provide in two different module. It creates an instance for each module, that's why it is not working.

Comment: @GeoAstronaute so how should I be providing it??

Comment: @GeoAstronaute Ive taken it off the provider list in mainModule and its still not working..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your issue here is that you provide your service in two different modules, that end up with two instances of your service. The simplest way if you are using Angular v6 is to use the **providedIn** flag in your service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
class myService {}
```

With this way you don't need to provide your service in the providers array of any module, it will be automatically provided in the root injector.

Documentation about this can be found here : [Angular providers](https://angular.io/guide/providers).

If your are using Angular v5 you should only provide your service in your AppModule.

Comment: Im using angular 5, and I have taken the service out of my mainModule and it still doesnt seem to be working

Comment: Okay so I removed every instance of the service and set it up again and now it is working, thank you!

Comment: No problem, glad to help !

Comment: Lord! also, you can't put it in the providers[] of other modules.

Answer (score 3):

In your service, write a new method like this:

```
popupSource = new BehaviorSubject<any>('');

getPopupSource() { 
   return this.popupSource.asObservable();
}
```

And subscribe to that instead of subscribing directly to the subject itself. You could just add the 'asObservable()' part whenever you subscribe to it instead of creating an entirely new method, but I like the separate method so I can keep the Subject private, and I usually subscribe to something multiple times in different places throughout an app, so it cuts down on repetition.

In your component :

```
this._service.getPopupSource().subscribe( result => { etc...})
```

EDIT :

Demo recreation of your scenario - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n6esd5

Comment: Strange...  I made a demo recreating your example and it works like I would expect. https://angular-n6esd5.stackblitz.io   More code might help

Comment: Thats what is so weird, I literally have like 20 other functions in that service that work except for this one..

Comment: @GeoAstronaute seems to think how Its provided.. because its been provided twice in my mainModule and my appModule... but Ive removed it from the mainModule and it still doesnt seem to be working

Comment: When I read their explanation I thought that was probably the issue too - generally if you want to provide the same instance of a service globally throughout your app, you'd provide it to the root-most module (in your case app module). If that's not working then consider me as confused as you are

Comment: Awww yeaaaaaaaa

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there a reason why you shouldnt make your source public?? why not just subscribe to it directly??

Comment: I don't know if there's a really compelling reason, I just generally like knowing for sure that a subject can only be controlled from within the service itself. Makes it easier to debug and reason about stuff when my apps get big and I can't remember every iota of code off the top of my head anymore. Private in typescript is really only 'kinda private' in practice, so its probably just personal preference

Comment: @SmokeyDawson the reason to keep the Subject private and return an Observable is so that only your service can call next() on the Subject. Anyone can then subscribe but all updates must go through the service.

Answer (score 0):

You may not have the same instance of service, my same problem was that I had `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root'})` for my service, but also I put this service in the component providers [] array, just remove the providers array, then it works